# Prettier indentation settings - HTML tree structure is too narrow

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

im trying to make wider spaces between HTML parent and child elements. I tried with many settings but my tree is still super unreadable. I can't see what exactly each div contains.

The current look:
[image: Current look]

I'm trying to achieve wider structure, like this one:
[image]

```json
"editor.tabSize": 2,
```

Comment: you are using a variable size font, target image uses a mono-space font with tab-size 4

Answer (score -1):

You're using a [variable-width font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface#Proportion). Spaces in variable-width fonts are often much thinner than other glyphs/characters. The image of what you want is using a [monospace font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) (where every glyph/character has the same width). Use the `editor.fontFamily` setting in the settings.json file. You'll need to consult your OS / Desktop environment to see what fonts you have installed for selection. If there's one you want and don't have, you'll need to install it.